# Initializing values in C struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am very new to C and I am wondering if this is allowed and if so, how do I do it correctly?

This code gives me tons of compiler errors.  I am trying to create a structure with 3 character arrays (initialized to null characters `'\0'`) and initialize one of these structs with the name `S`.

```
struct Structure{
    char array1[3] = { '\0' };
    char array2[30]= { '\0' };
    char array3[30]= { '\0' };
} S;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That is not allowed.

Types (your `struct Structure` is a type) in C have no value. What has values are objects.

You can create an object of a struture type and initialize all of it,recursively if needed, to 0 with what I call the *universal zero initializer*.

```
struct Structure {
    char array1[3];
    char array2[30];
    char array3[30];
} S = {0};
```

Comment: Why do you have "s = {0}" instead of the null character "\0". Is there a difference?

Comment: C automatically converts a plain `0` to the kind of zero needed for whatever it is used (`0` (int), `'\0'` (char), `0.0` (double), `NULL` (pointer)). I tend to always use `0` rather than the proper type. Apart from that consistency thing, there is no significative difference.

Comment: @pmg, `'\0'` is not of type `char` but `int`.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There are two separate things:

1. Declaring the structure of the `struct` - what parts it's made of.
2. Defining a specific instance of this struct. When doing so, you can also initialize some or all fields.

Your code only declares the layout, and doesn't create an actual instance. So it can't initialize.

Answer (score 1):

u can't initaialize values in elements of struct.
 correct initialization is like this-
`struct Structure s = {0};`
correct declaration is

```
struct Structure{
    char array1[3] ;
    char array2[30];
    char array3[30];
} S;
```

Comment: Why do you have "s = {0}" instead of the null character "\0".  Is there a difference?

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma:   in c language NULL is defined as 0, u can see this in null.h header files